# SVG path, set position of start point?

Tags: html, svg

I'm a bit confused.  I created a dashed line with arrowheads:

```
    <svg width="995" height="100" viewBox="0 0 995 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
    <marker id="arrowLeft" markerWidth="25" markerHeight="25" refX="0" refY="10">
      <path fill="#662D91" d="M0 12.5l25-12.5v25z"/>
    </marker>
    <marker id="arrowRight" markerWidth="25" markerHeight="25" refX="0" refY="0">
      <path d="M0 25v-25l25 12.5-25 12.5z" fill="#662D91"/>
    </marker>
</defs>
<path d="M0 0h950" stroke="#662D91" stroke-width=".75" stroke-dasharray="5,2" fill="#000" marker-start="url(#arrowLeft)" marker-end="url(#arrowRight)"/>
<text class="arrow-labels" transform="translate(300 10)">ACTIONS</text>
```

But the path for the line currently is at 0,0 and I want it to start at 0,20.  However, if I change my above code to M0,20 the whole line disappears.  What am I missing here?

I realize I can use `transform`, but I'm curious as to why setting `M` coordinates is not working.

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/xmxrqg04/#&togetherjs=UvcvSsGuaL

Comment: Seeme OK when I tried it.

Comment: When I change it to `<path d="M0,50 0h600" ` the line disappears.  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What do expect the 0 to do before the h? That's where you're going wrong, you can't have an odd number of values after an M

Comment: That's the issue, you're right.  That's the way the svg code came in from Sketch.  I was wondering why that zero was there!  Changing the code to ` <path d="M0,10 h600"` works like I expected.  Thanks.

Comment: The code in the SVG looks correct (`"M0 0h950"`). It seems the OP just made a mistake when altering it. `"M0 0h950"` should have become `"M0 20h950"`, not `"M0,20 0h950"`.

Comment: I was following the description here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html, "setting and moving the pen":  `M0,20 h950`